# How can I change the home directory's location along with the default install directory?

Tags: installation, home-directory

I decided to use Ubuntu as my main operating system tonight and have been setting everything up. I installed it on a 64GB SSD, however I want my home directory and default install location to be on my 1TB HDD. How would I go about setting this up? Thanks.

Comment: check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: @ManulaWaidyanatha What about changing the default install location?

Comment: what do you mean by default installation location. Is it /home default installation location ????

Comment: @ManulaWaidyanatha: I am sorry. I am relatively new to Ubuntu and am still getting used to its file structure. I found http://askubuntu.com/questions/24396/how-do-i-change-software-centers-default-installation-path, which should solve my problem. Thanks anyways!